# How to create this tabular data structure with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have several two-column tables that i want to join together with numpy. Each table has x and y columns. I need all the x columns joined together, with the y values matched up to the corresponding x. If an x value doesn't have a corresponding y, it should be None.

I'm not so good at explaining, so an example will probably be better:

```
x1=np.arange(10)
y1=np.random.random(10)
x2=np.arange(4,12)
y2=np.random.random(8)
x1,y1,x2,y2
# (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
#  array([ 0.9697099 ,  0.73551173,  0.47020836,  0.65181839,  0.978934  ,
    0.18953898,  0.46405499,  0.50087478,  0.06777209,  0.45780724]),
#  array([ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]),
#  array([ 0.4871265 ,  0.13677392,  0.17808162,  0.92777264,  0.43666515,
    0.96582633,  0.8801327 ,  0.96819467]))
```

I want it to result in this:

```
(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]),
 array([0.9697099017727184, 0.7355117301087176, 0.47020836280801315,
   0.6518183854825162, 0.9789339965301322, 0.18953898439009775,
   0.46405499422617846, 0.5008747838856135, 0.06777208803132984,
   0.45780724068543743, None, None], dtype=object),
 array([None, None, None, None, 0.4871264999476407, 0.13677391508082204,
   0.17808162175961462, 0.927772639273923, 0.43666515340304246,
   0.9658263324455688, 0.880132700341068, 0.9681946747550136], dtype=object))
```

I tried searching but couldn't find anything. Perhaps i wasn't formulating my search correctly.

Comment: You mean that x and y are both a column, but do not have equal shape, as `x2` has a diffent shape than `y2`?

Comment: @Chiel What do you mean? `x2` and `y2` both have a shape of `(8,)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to do this easily by pass the arrays as values in a dict with the column names defined as `x` and `y1` and `y2` respectively for each df:

```
In [280]:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x1=np.arange(10)
y1=np.random.random(10)
x2=np.arange(4,12)
y2=np.random.random(8)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x1,'y1':y1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x2,'y2':y2})
df1

Out[280]:
   x        y1
0  0  0.951029
1  1  0.974854
2  2  0.391443
3  3  0.487474
4  4  0.430653
5  5  0.737643
6  6  0.547114
7  7  0.770040
8  8  0.475704
9  9  0.577185

In [281]:
df2

Out[281]:
    x        y2
0   4  0.894808
1   5  0.534086
2   6  0.257441
3   7  0.658060
4   8  0.443201
5   9  0.319719
6  10  0.360698
7  11  0.542051
```

We can then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) performing an `outer` type merge this will match on the common `x` column and auto insert `NaN` where there are no corresponding values:

```
In [279]:    
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

Out[279]:
       x        y1        y2
0    0.0  0.714475       NaN
1    1.0  0.628956       NaN
2    2.0  0.262343       NaN
3    3.0  0.022310       NaN
4    4.0  0.271616  0.343311
5    5.0  0.075175  0.503210
6    6.0  0.424153  0.874114
7    7.0  0.677780  0.677042
8    8.0  0.986892  0.672466
9    9.0  0.383558  0.896930
10  10.0       NaN  0.871810
11  11.0       NaN  0.510811
```

You can convert to a np array by calling the `values` attribute:

```
In [282]:
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').values

Out[282]:
array([[  0.        ,   0.95102908,          nan],
       [  1.        ,   0.97485407,          nan],
       [  2.        ,   0.39144301,          nan],
       [  3.        ,   0.48747382,          nan],
       [  4.        ,   0.43065283,   0.89480821],
       [  5.        ,   0.73764321,   0.53408613],
       [  6.        ,   0.54711396,   0.25744133],
       [  7.        ,   0.77003988,   0.65806007],
       [  8.        ,   0.47570448,   0.44320138],
       [  9.        ,   0.57718451,   0.31971908],
       [ 10.        ,          nan,   0.36069758],
       [ 11.        ,          nan,   0.54205073]])
```

Comment: Wish i had known about Pandas earlier. It'll make some of my other code logic much simpler.

Comment: pandas is great for data manipulation and is compatible with interfaces that accept np arrays, there is a slight performance penalty but this is mainly due to better type handling and fault tolerance for invalid/missing values

Comment: FWIW I ended up setting the x columns as the DataFrame index and performing `join`, which lets me have two columns plus an index column, which makes more sense for my data.